# How can I refactor my controller method to make it smaller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller in my Laravel application, it is responsible for storing DNS records, at first, it stores it in my own database then afterwards a job is dispatched for it to store it in DNS Management Service as well, then I return a message to user implying the given job has been submitted, now my question is that, how can I refactor this piece of code?

```
public function zoneStore(StoreDnsRequest $request)
{
    $zone = Zone::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->user_id,
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'config' =>
            [
                "zone" => strtolower($request['name']),
                "group_name" => 'MainNameservers',
                "nt_zone_id" => "",
                "nt_group_id" => '11',
                "owner_group_id" => '11',
                "mailaddr" => 'webmaster.'.strtolower($request['name']),
                "description" => $request['description'],
                "ttl" => $request['ttl']
            ],
        'service_config' =>
            [
                "zone" => strtolower($request['name']),
                "group_name" => 'MainNameservers',
                "nt_zone_id" => "",
                "nt_group_id" => '11',
                "owner_group_id" => '11',
                "mailaddr" => 'webmaster.'.strtolower($request['name']),
                "description" => $request['description'],
                "ttl" => $request['ttl']
            ],
        'service_unique_id'=>"",
        'source_type_id' => 8,
        'source_id' => 4,
        'uuid' =>  Str::uuid()->toString(),
        'status' => 'building'
    ]);
    $task = TaskController::info($zone->uuid, ZoneBeacons::$create, __('dns.zone.message.creating'),'pending',"200");
    broadcast(new DnsActions(ZoneBeacons::$create, DnsActions::$PENDING, $zone, $task));
    createZone::dispatch($zone, $task);
    return response(["data"=>["message"=>__("dns.zone.message.pending"),"status"=>true]], 201);
}
```

Comment: one thing you can do is to use repository pattern to remove all that create method, 
see https://asperbrothers.com/blog/implement-repository-pattern-in-laravel/

Comment: I don't really see a problem with this code. Depending on your application you could set default values in your model for the attributes that have fixed  values in your array.

Comment: One thing I recommend is to move all of this request logic to StoreDnsRequest since Controllers should really be used like this.

Comment: Maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ could be a better option for refactoring questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is many ways to achieve small controllers by delegate functions to separet pice of logic. I can suggest you two examples. For first you may create action class ( e.g like those in [fortify](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/tree/1.x/src/Actions) ) which will be responsible for creating models, validating or any other stuff.

```php
// App\Actions\CreateZone
class CreateZone {

    public function execute( array $data ) {
        return Zone::create( [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->user_id,
            'name' => $data[ 'name' ],
            'config' =>
                [
                    "zone" => strtolower( $data[ 'name' ] ),
                    "group_name" => 'MainNameservers',
                    "nt_zone_id" => "",
                    "nt_group_id" => '11',
                    "owner_group_id" => '11',
                    "mailaddr" => 'webmaster.' . strtolower( $data[ 'name' ] ),
                    "description" => $data[ 'description' ],
                    "ttl" => $data[ 'ttl' ]
                ],
            'service_config' =>
                [
                    "zone" => strtolower( $data[ 'name' ] ),
                    "group_name" => 'MainNameservers',
                    "nt_zone_id" => "",
                    "nt_group_id" => '11',
                    "owner_group_id" => '11',
                    "mailaddr" => 'webmaster.' . strtolower( $data[ 'name' ] ),
                    "description" => $data[ 'description' ],
                    "ttl" => $data[ 'ttl' ]
                ],
            'service_unique_id' => "",
            'source_type_id' => 8,
            'source_id' => 4,
            'uuid' => Str::uuid()->toString(),
            'status' => 'building'
        ] );
    }
}
```

Second you may delegate dispatching jobs etc. to [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) ( or if you prefer create own event/listener ).

```php
// App\Observers\ZoneObserver
class ZoneObserver {

    public function created( Zone $zone ) {
        $task = TaskController::info(
            $zone->uuid, 
            ZoneBeacons::$create, 
            __('dns.zone.message.creating'),
            'pending',
            "200"
        );
        
        broadcast(new DnsActions(ZoneBeacons::$create, DnsActions::$PENDING, $zone, $task));
        
        createZone::dispatch($zone, $task);
    }
}
```

Remember to register new observer.

```php
// App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot
Zone::observe(ZoneObserver::class);
```

With this two approach your controller may look like this.

```php
public function zoneStore(StoreDnsRequest $request, CreateZone $createZone)
{
    $createZone->execute( $request->validated() );

    return response([
        "data" => [
            "message" => __("dns.zone.message.pending"),
            "status"=>true
        ]
    ], 201);
}
```

Hope this helps you a little.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring is not about one file/controller/method, it's about the whole project. It's about identifyig the redundancy of code and ways to better organise it.

For example, In your controller you create a "Zone" and it triggers broadcast and a job.

If you have another place where a zone is created, to write less code, you would need to move the broadcast and the job inside the create method and have this create method somewhere where you can access it from both place (this controller and the "other place")

You can also refactor code by grouping code by concern. For example any broadcast event should use Broadcast::class that way you can overload the defined methods without having to rewrite all the places where it is triggered, instead you rewrite the Broadcast::class.

Keep in ming that in this day and age, with the speed of processors, it is better to have a human readable code that have your code do 10 less steps in a millions steps project (compiled code wise).